# Ruby on Rails, form_for com 3 níveis

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou tentando criar comment, através do form_for de 3 níveis:
    *Article > Item > Comment*

```
Controller:
 def new
  @comment = Comment.new
 end
```

Eu já tentei de diversas maneiras, e todas dão erro. Vejam o que eu tentei e o erro que retornou:

1ª Tentativa:

`<%= form_for([@item, @item.comments.build]) do |f| %>`

> Erro: undefined method `item_comments_path' for

2ª Tentativa:

`<%= form_for ([@item, @comment]) do |f| %>`

> Erro: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

3ª Tentativa:

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>  
        <%= f.fields_for @item do |i| %>  
            <%= i.fields_for @comments do |c| %>
```

> Erro: undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Não sei mais o que tentar, como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Descobri o problema:
Eu estava dentro da página show de item, mas renderizando uma partial de add comment. Eu achei que ele iria passar pelo controller de Comment, mas ele estava passando apenas pelo controller de Item.

Answer (score 1):

Article.rb

```
  has_many  :items #repare no plural
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
```

Item.rb

```
  belongs_to :article, required: false  #repare no singular
  has_many  :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

Comment.rb

```
  belongs_to :item, required: false
```

No controller das classes pai tem que ter no def new @pai.filhos.build
exemplo (estou considerando que article é pai de item que é pai de comment:

articles_controller.rb

```
def new
   @article = Article.new
   @article.items.build
end
```

Use seu terceiro form.

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>  
        <%= f.fields_for @item do |i| %>  
            <%= i.fields_for @comments do |c| %>
```

Geralmente erros do tipo:
       Erro: undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass
são corrigindo-se inicializando o model-name na action do controller que vc está acessando:

```
def action
  @model-name = Model-name.new
end
```

ou

```
def action
   @model-name-pai = Model-name-pai.new
   @model-name-pai.model-names.build  #(repare no plural do filho: model-nameS)
end
```

Comment: Paulo! Super obrigado pela sua contribuição. O meu erro era um pouco mais bobo. Como eu estava criando um comment, achei que deveria entrar na action new de comment, mas como eu estava em show_item, e apenas add comment através de uma partial, eu estava esquecendo de conferir no controller de Item.

De qqer forma, achei super interessante sua abordagem. Agora está funcionando aqui, mas não utilizei "accepts_nested_attributes_for".

Estou fazendo errado ou podem existir várias formas corretas neste caso?

Comment: Se o seu está funcionando então acho que está certo! rs Sou iniciante tb.